# Why -since this set is also closed in $E$, and $E$ is connected, it follows that it must be all of $E$-?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, solution-verification

> If $\bf{f}$ is a differentiable mapping of a connected open set $E
>  \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, and if
>    $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$, show that
>    $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ is constant in $E$.

The answer is given [here](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%209.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y). The question that I have about the answer provided is:

Why can we make the following statement (last sentence)?

> Since this set is also closed in $E$, and $E$ is connected, it follows
>    that it must be all of $E$.

Can someone provide an proof for this statement based on the *definition* of what it means for $E$ to be connected, i.e. not a union of two nonempty separated sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $E$ is connected if and only if the only clopen subsets of $E$ are $\varnothing$ and the same set $E$. You can find the proof of this fact right [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_iff_no_Proper_Clopen_Sets).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little unclear, but how does this help in the proof?

Comment: The set $K = \{\textbf{x} :\, \textbf{f}(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{f}(\textbf{x}^0)\} = \textbf{f}^{-1}(\{\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}^0)\})$ is open, closed and non-empty, since it contains $\textbf{x}^0$. So, $K = E$ is the only option, since $E$ is connected.